# Creating a MySQL stored procedure to update records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm converting all of my existing MSSQL databases and stored procedures am stuck on a new stored procedure where I need to update an existing record.  The procedure gets called from a web form once a record has been inserted into the database and en email sent successfully (or at least passed off to the SMTP server)

I've had a working procedure in MSSQL for a long time but am trying to convert it to MySQL.  I'm passing in 3 variables - a bit indicating the email got sent, a string indicating which SMTP server has been used to sent the email and a unique record id so I'll know what record to update. I'm also adding the date and time to another field to know when the procedure ran.

I've got the following but keep getting an error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 - yet I don't see anything off at line 7 - at least to my eye.

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Test`(
  `emailSent_In` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `emailTransport_In` VARCHAR(100),
  `formSecret_In` VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
  SET @`query` := CONCAT('UPDATE ',`tbl_JustSayThanks`,' 
  SET `emailSent` = `emailSent_In`,
  `emailTransport` = ',`emailTransport_In`,',
`emailSentDate` = NOW()
    WHERE `formSecret` = ', `formSecret_In`, '');
  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
  EXECUTE `stmt`;
       @`query` := NULL;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Just FYI, I'm using the CONCAT based on a previous answer I received from wchiquito and will be passing in the table name eventually.  But, I wanted to get it to work on a simplified level before going there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is wrong:

```
SET @`query` := CONCAT('UPDATE ',`tbl_JustSayThanks`,'
```

because you seem to be concatenating your SQL text with the *value* of `tbl_JustSayThanks`, but I think you mean to use the identifier itself. This should therefore be:

```
SET @`query` := CONCAT('UPDATE `tbl_JustSayThanks`',
```

The following is wrong:

```
`emailTransport` = ',`emailTransport_In`,',
```

because the variable is a VARCHAR but you don't quote it as a string literal in your SQL statement. It's easy to get mixed up with the multiple levels of quoting. It should be:

```
`emailTransport` = ''', `emailTransport_In`, ''',
```

The following is wrong for the same reason:

```
WHERE `formSecret` = ', `formSecret_In`, '');
```

it should be:

```
WHERE `formSecret` = ''', `formSecret_In`, '''');
```

This still suffers from SQL injection problems, unless you can guarantee that the input parameters are safe (which is not a good assumption). If you need to concatenate values into your SQL expressions, you should use the `QUOTE()` function to do escaping:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('
  UPDATE tbl_JustSayThanks 
  SET emailSent = ', QUOTE(emailSent_In), '
      emailTransport = ', QUOTE(emailTransport_In), '
      emailSentDate = NOW()
  WHERE formSecret = ', QUOTE(formSecret_In));
```

More comments:

- You don't need to delimit every identifier with back-ticks, only those that conflict with SQL reserved words, or contain whitespace or punctuation or international characters. None of your identifiers you show require delimiting.
- When you use prepared statements, you should use query parameters with the `?` placeholders, intead of concatenating variables into the SQL string. You don't quote parameter placeholders in your SQL query. That way you won't run into hard-to-debug syntax errors like the ones you found.

Here's an example showing the fixes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test(
  emailSent_In BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  emailTransport_In VARCHAR(100),
  formSecret_In VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
  SET @query = '
    UPDATE tbl_JustSayThanks
    SET emailSent = ?,
        emailTransport = ?,
        emailSentDate = NOW()
    WHERE formSecret = ?';
  SET @es = emailSent_In;
  SET @et = emailTransport_In;
  SET @fs = formSecret_In;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @es, @et, @fs;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Final comment:

- Your example query has no dynamic syntax elements, only dynamic *values*. So you don't need to use a prepared statement at all.

This is how I'd really write the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test(
  emailSent_In BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  emailTransport_In VARCHAR(100),
  formSecret_In VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
  UPDATE tbl_JustSayThanks
  SET emailSent = emailSent_In,
      emailTransport = emailTransport_In,
      emailSentDate = NOW()
  WHERE formSecret = formSecret_In;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You should also be aware that MySQL stored procedures are greatly inferior to Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL doesn't keep compiled stored procedures, it doesn't support packages, it doesn't have a debugger... I recommend you do not use MySQL stored procedures. Use application code instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the great information - I had no idea about a lot of that so it's great to know.  I wish we could stay with MSSQL but it isn't an option due to a variety of reasons.

Comment: Nuts - got sidetracked and didn't finish my original comment....  Running either example is returning an error of 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7' in the first example and line 11 in the second.  I'm not seeing the error myself so am at a loss how to fix but am researching...

Comment: You probably didn't change the `DELIMITER`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html for help.

Comment: Sigh - took too long again - I started by adding Delimeter // prior to the create, got another error and then added the check for the procedure and it did run.  So much new to learn - or at least figure out what means what in comparison to MSSQL.  As a dyslexic, reading the manual is  partially helpful - places like this are much better for me.  Now all I need to do is change it so I can pass in a table name.  That's why I was going with a concatenate - it's based on another sproc I got here that lets me pass in a table name and search for a record id rather than having multiple procedures.

Comment: Anyway - thanks so much for all the help and all of the guidance for the future.  It's given me much to work with.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test(
  emailSent_In BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  emailTransport_In VARCHAR(100),
  formSecret_In VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
  UPDATE tbl_JustSayThanks
  SET emailSent = emailSent_In,
      emailTransport = emailTransport_In,
      emailSentDate = NOW()
  WHERE formSecret = formSecret_In;
END$$
DELIMITER ;