# MYSQL - Concatenate part of a column name and its index number

Tags: mysql, database-design, prepared-statement, concatenation

I would like to concatenate a column and its index (numerical name) inside of a SELECT statement in MySQL.

For example there are 4 columns: (Column1, Column2,Column3...ColumnN). Instead of updating the values by referring to them by name, I hope to use a variable named 'index' and attach it to the end of the word "Column".

- e.g. (Column(index),Column(index)...)

I have tried the `CONCAT()` and `CONCAT_WS` functions from the MySQL documentation.
   For example, if I set the value of the variable `index` = 3, it results in the following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('Column','3')`

The alternative would be to redesign database and its relations and I wish to avoid this.

Is what I am attempting possible for **column names** or simply strings within the database?

**Edit:**

```
$score_update = "UPDATE Users 
 SET CONCAT ('USER_module','$module_chosen_index') ='$module_quiz_score' 
 WHERE USER_firstname = '$username'";
```

The values of the `$module_chosen_index` can be (1,2...15) and the column title if I entered it and didn't use `CONCAT()` is `USER_module3`.

Comment: HI, just my opinion, but could you possibly put any SQL in code blocks? Way easier to read that way!!!

Comment: You can only do this with dynamic SQL.  You have a poor database design, and should probably be storing the columns in separate *rows*.

Comment: @Chrips the code would be standard CONCAT() function. Like thus: SELECT CONCAT('Column','$index') WHERE... . It's a hypothetical situation. I will reevaluate the database design and read up on dynamic SQL as Gordon Linoff suggests.

Comment: Can we look at an example of your query? and also what is the version of MySQL you're using? thanks

Comment: @tcadidot0 the query itself isn't helpful in my opinion but this is it.      
         $score_update = "UPDATE Users SET CONCAT ('USER_module','$module_chosen_index') ='$module_quiz_score' WHERE USER_firstname = '$username'"; The values of the $module_chosen_index can be (1,2...15) and the column title if I entered it and didn't use CONCAT() is USER_module3.

Comment: @Tedinoz thank you for simplifying and improving readability.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but is this PHP? Will it be possible to obtain the table names outside the `UPDATE` query?

Comment: @tcadidot0 the ability to concatenate the name is the issue whether inside or or outside of the update query.

Comment: I once encounter a situation where I need a query to create table based on current month and I found a way using MySQL stored-procedure. I assume that this can also be done to what you're trying to achieve but I'm not sure. Here's a link to one https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210884/10910692 and this was the link where I get my answer for my previous situation https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14401/191579 .